# Webdriver Assertions fails in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-9

I have ~50 automated test cases that works like a charm in both Chrome and Firefox, but IE just won't do it (too bad IE is required).

IE fails at assertions (not all assertions, but a vast majority of them) because (I think) it tries to assert too quickly, e.g. the page is not rendered fast enough.

Here is a piece of code that works in Chrome and FF, but not IE:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicityWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to(targetAdminServer());
Assert.assertTrue("The startpage is displayed", driver.getTitle().startsWith("Admin Portal -"));
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:j_id4:username")).sendKeys(loginSAUsername());
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:j_id6:password")).sendKeys(loginSAPassword());
driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:login")).click();
Assert.assertTrue("Login successful", driver.getTitle().contains("Welcome,"));
```

Where I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Login successful
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at first.example.project.webdriver.AddUser.I_am_logged_in_as_a_administrator(AddUser.java:36)
at ✽.Given I am logged in as a "administrator"(C:\path\cucumberfeature1.feature:5)
```

What I can see during execution is that webdriver fills the fields with username and password and then dies right after clicking the login button.

UPDATE:
I may add that if I add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` before the Assertion that fails it works just fine.

UPDATE2: A friend asked me if it might be because that IE usually runs at 32-bit while the rest of the browsers runs at 64-bit (since I have a 64-bit OS), could this have anything to do with it?

UPDATE3: Tried with both 64-bit and 32-bit IEDriverServer, but none of them asserted in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After login click you need some wait for element.
When title will be changed you could check, but not before that event.

Comment: Then how come it works in Firefox and Chrome? Shouldn't they require a wait then as well?

Comment: they are writed better, so they recognize page is refreshed. IEDriver is more buggy. Still check for change on element not cost much and is somehow expected.

Answer (score 0):

Config as below:

1. Enter Registry Editor
2. Refer to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl
3. Found key FEATURE_BFCACHE, if not found -> Create 1 DWORD iexplore.exe, value=0
4. Try run your test case on IE and notice problem is resolved or not
   -> If fail
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl and create iexplore.exe, value=0